# Old front tyre motorbike worn to one side

Tags: motorcycle, tires

I have recently changed the front tyre on my old bike (cbr600Fx). I noticed the old tyre was worn to one side, I checked the bearings when I was changing it and they seemed fine, I am thinking it could be suspension is unbalanced, maybe the wheel is unbalanced, or the forks need bleeding, any other issues it could be?

Comment: A bent frame...

Comment: Some riders don't sit centrally, so the bike is leaning to one side all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly normal for a motorcycle front tire to be worn on one side more than the other.  The explanation is simple, you travel a much greater distance when you turn LEFT in places where vehicles drive on the RIGHT or vice versa depending on which side of the road you normally drive on.

Here is a link to an explanation:

[Tire Wear Explanation](https://www.rockymountainatvmc.com/rm-rider-exchange/just-faqs-understanding-motorcycle-tire-wear/)

Scroll down to the section that is titled:

> My front tire often wears more on the left side than the right. Is this an indication of a problem with my bike?

There is an image there that shows what's going on.

Comment: also, most roads are not flat, but domed for water run off. If you drive on the right, then the left side of the tyre has more contact than the right on average. Fit new tyres and find some twisty roads.